# Is Yahoo Messenger, Gtalk, Hotmail Messenger now available on ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: 13.04, yahoo, gtalk

I am a messenger user and most of all like using all the messengers including yahoo, hotmail, gtalk. I want to know whether ubuntu now has all these messenger version that works perfectly on their OS.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can chat using all these messengers on Ubuntu. However its not recommended to use their companies programs. Yahoo messenger looks like its from 1999.

What I suggest you do is install a 'messenger program'. There are a few to pick from so I am going to give you two options.
One is [Pidgin](http://www.pidgin.im/), the other is [Empathy](https://live.gnome.org/Empathy) (more can come in the comments).
Pick either one you like, that's really up to what you feel is comfortable to you (if you ask me I use pidgin, but that is only me. I also recommend it because it works on windows, so you can try it out before you move to Ubuntu).

You can install pidgin using the command:

```
apt-get install pidgin
```

and Empathy (if not already installed):

```
apt-get install empathy
```

Once you install a messenger application, you can add to it ALL your messenger accounts. Yes! This means you can access your contacts and messages from both gtalk, hotmail and yahoo from the same program!
It works smoothly, and is faster, because you don't have to open three different programs to do the same thing.

Comment: yahoo 1999 lulz.  acts like it too

Answer (score 0):

absolutely, you can  use empathy (comes pre-installed) or you can use pidgin (the one i prefer and use)
however, or you can download many messengers from ubuntu software center

or you can visit the website of service, for example once you go to facebook site, you can chat with friends from the browser directly

moreover,  [EBuddy](http://www.ebuddy.com) is a site for application called EBuddy you can download it to your mobile phone, however, in this site you can sign in to all your accounts (Facebook, Yahoo, messenger and more)

Today, Instant messaging others become very important and can be found everywhere, it's like finding the clock